# Div aligning right and changing x location depending on other Divs on the right side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alignment

Overall I would like to have something like this **jsfiddle.net/DSghU/**

Just that the the whole thing is not sliding out to the left. It shall **slide** **out** to the **right**. So that by clicking on the button the button is going completely to the right side.

### Edit

I was able to solve the first question: jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/7hne1d0b/

But now I'm looking for a small fix on that. I really dislike that the text is braking when toggled out. How can I set it so that the text is not braking?

### Edit 2

The current solution is already cool. But there is just another small issue with the other content. It's moving to the bottom. So how can these toggle elements really be just like an overlay. Here an example: jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/7hne1d0b/4/ I want that the other text(on the left) is staying as it is. And image there is a SVG instead!

### Edit 3

Found it out. You need another inner div: jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/7hne1d0b/5/ But I don't think that's a cool solution for this right? If someone finds out something way better, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by text breaking? Are you talking about the shaking at the end point of toggle ?

Comment: Added info in the comment of the first answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was pretty simple. Just a bit of CSS needed to be changed and the order and elements in the HTML edited.

This is what I wanted to have: jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/7hne1d0b/2/

Answer (score 2):

Is this correct. Please have a look at following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zxwo3ack/16/

basically I just added a few things to the css

```
#myDiv {
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    color:Green;
    background-color:#eee;
    border:2px solid #333;
    text-align:justify;
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#button{
    position: absolute;
    top:80px;
    right:0px;
    float:right;
}
.other_details{
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    float:right;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:5px;
    margin-left:2px;
}
```

Comment: With braking I mean, that e.g. at the very end the first line still should be "Lorem Ipsum is simply" but instead much more less. I don't know if this is even possible with changing the width. But maybe you know something.

Comment: Still confused what do you mean ? @ kwoxer

Comment: Ohh already have it =) I just needed an inner div with a fixed width. That's how I wanted to have it: http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/7hne1d0b/2/ Maybe you could tell me what I have described in a bad way so that I can improve on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve your goal you will need to animate either `left` position or `margin-left`. In both cases respectic div should be wrapped with one more container with overflow: hidden on it.

```
var targetWidth = $('#myDiv').css("margin-left") == "200px" ? "0px" : "200px";

if (!$("#myDiv").is(":visible")) {
    $("#myDiv").show();
}

$('#myDiv').animate({marginLeft: targetWidth}, duration, function () {
    if ($(this).css("margin-left") == "200px") {
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7hne1d0b/3/

Comment: Have a look on my solution. That's how I wanted it = http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/7hne1d0b/2/ Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your solution is even simpler!

Comment: Well thanks but one remaining issue is that I have a SVG in the background. And if I set it above it moves the SVG to the bottom. So how could I say that this div is just like an overlay. Not harming any other elements. But still having the other area on the left side of the toggline area?

Comment: Maybe you can help me out on the last thing =) Edit above.